# Mail attachement with IMAP protocol

Tags: c#, smtp, imap, email-attachments

I have a glitch when i want store mail message to a folders with IMAP protocol. I have encapsulated in a method a sending mail notification.
This method have two actions :
- Send mail message with standard SmtpClient.
- Push in the "Sent" folder the mail message with Imap protocol.
I would like to conserve the sending message for tracing it. My message contains a text body and some attachments. The end user receive correctly the message and the attachments, but in my "Sent" directory the message is correctly presented the message contains the attachments but with a size to zero and is not readable. I use S22.imap NuGet package for dialog in IMAP.

With the Imap protocol is it necessary to add some actions to stored attachements to the server ?

```
   public void SendMail(MailMessage p_Message)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = Constante.Constante.MaillingConstante.MaillingHost,
            Port = Constante.Constante.MaillingConstante.SmtpMaillingPort,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Timeout = 30 * 1000,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(p_Message.From.Address, <pwd>)
        };

        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(p_Message);

            // The default port for IMAP over SSL is 993.
            using (ImapClient imapClient = new ImapClient(Constante.Constante.MaillingConstante.MaillingHost, Constante.Constante.MaillingConstante.ImapMaillingPort, p_Message.From.Address, <pwd>, AuthMethod.Login, true))
            {
                imapClient.StoreMessage(p_Message, false, "Sent");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              .......
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean 'Folders'?  IMAP doesn't refer to collections of messages as directories.  And instead of 'push' you may mean 'upload' or 'append'.  Your message as is is a bit confusing.

Comment: Max Yes I store the message in a "Sent" folder.

Comment: I found the problem. It's necessary to rewind the ContentStream of the attachment at the beginning. I looping on the attachments collection and set the ContentStream.Position=0.

Comment: If you discovered a solution, please answer your own question and mark it accepted.